# Windows 2008 R2 Print Server load 32 bit drivers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, print-server

I am trying to load HP 32bit drivers on w2k8r2.

For my other printer deployments, I have had no problems but all of the conventional workarounds (i.e. installing on a 32bit pc then pushing it to the server, etc.) is not helping me.

For example, if I reference the test page printout from a 32 bit pc that I have manually installed the driver on it lists:

Driver Name: UNIDRV.DLL
Data File: HPLJ45P6.GPD
Config file: UNIDRV.HLP
...etc.

These are all either dynamic link library files or help files. The 2k8r2 server wants a .inf file and there is none to be found in the entire directory listed in the printer test page? The server will not let me choose another filetype and of course, I cannot install the driver directly to the print server.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, this is an HP printer so it may be slightly different for other vendors.

1. Goto HP.Com and find printer model
2. download both x64 and x32 versions of the drivers
3. Run the driver packages on the servers, x64 will install x32 will fail.
4. goto the folder where the driver packages installed. for me it was C:\HP Universal Print Driver. verify the files have extracted.
5. goto the printer on the server > Properties > Sharing > Additional Drivers
6. Check the x86 box and click ok
7. when prompted for driver, choose the directory where the drivers extracted.
8. Find DLL and click ok.

This has worked for me in the same situation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Your input was partly helpful but the key is to make sure the x86/x64 drivers are the exact same version. Also, the x86 needs to be installed on an x86 architecture and OS and then the driver can be pushed to the x64 server.